# How to update specific record in Realm Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, realm

I want to update specific record in Realm Objective-C. Currently, I have not found any code mention to update specific record. Please help me how to do it.

Below my code is add record in Realm. But I want to update record regarding to **cpID**.

```
RLMCoachPadItem *RMLCoachPad = [[RLMCoachPadItem alloc]init];
RMLCoachPad.cpID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", results.count+1];
RMLCoachPad.cpDescription = _txtMessage.text;
RMLCoachPad.cpTagId = @"";


RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[realm addObject:RMLCoachPad];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Comment: I'd recommend to not use the same class prefix like Realm does. It is used because the lack of namespacing in Objective-C to avoid naming conflicts. In addition it's a common convention to name variables beginning with an underscore and drop the class prefix there, e.g. `ABCCoachPad *coachPad = [ABCCoachPad new]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation on how to update objects [here](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#updating-objects).

Example from the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#updating-objects):

> You can also partially update objects with primary keys by passing the
>   subset of values you wish to update, along with the primary key:

```
// Assuming a "Book" with a primary key of `1` already exists.
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[Book createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:@{@"id": @1, @"price": @9000.0f}];
// the book's `title` property will remain unchanged.
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Assuming that `cpID` is your primary key for `RLMCoachPadItem` and you would like to update the description (`cpDescription`):

```
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[RLMCoachPadItem createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:@{@"cpID": @"idOfYourRMLCoachPad", @"cpDescription": @"new description"}];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Comment: No known class method for selector 'createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:'

Comment: Is `RLMCoachPadItem` a subclass of `RLMObject`?

Comment: yap, sure. @interface RLMCoachPadItem : RLMObject  <<

Comment: Is your realm version >= 0.92.0? Then it should be available as per the API reference: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#//api/name/createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue: